# I need regular expression to replace everything than certain text

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression which can extract time data in format as in following examples:

```
2 Hours
2 hours
2 Hours 30 minutes
2.5 hour
```

I'm trying to get it done and written following regular expression -

```
[^0-9\s(H|h)our(M|m)in\.]?
```

But when I test this - it matches characters 'our' and 'in' separately. I want to match only the words 'Hour' and 'hour' and not subset of their characters.

Comment: Can you give us samples of the exact input and exact expected output?

Comment: Do you know what is a character class?  (To elaborate, how would your _regex_ be considered if enclosed within `[` and `]`?)

Comment: which programming language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this?

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s(?:H|h)ours?(?:\s(\d+)\s(?:M|m)inutes?)?
```

The first group will be the number of hours, the second group is the number of minutes

Comment: Wow, surprising how similar our answers turned out to be!

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will do that for you:

`^(\d+(\.\d+)? (H|h)ours?( \d+ (m|M)in(utes?)?)?)$`

The first captured group `\1` or `$1` is what you want. It will contain the whole relevant string

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/xQ6rF3

Answer (score 0):

For `PHP` (PCRE) you can use:

```
/((?:\d+(?:[.\d]+)?\s+hours?)(?:\s+\d+?\s+minutes?)?)/i
```

**DEMO ->** http://regex101.com/r/lP3oM1